# Getting jQuery to load when creating a Wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am developing a wordpress theme and am having trouble getting jQuery to load up.
I have the following code in the functions.php file in my themes directory :

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', 'load_jquery' );

function load_jquery() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
```

And am testing whether it has loaded or not with this script in the header.php file of my theme:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

         alert("hello");
    });
```

Just cant seem to get the alert to show?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using wp_head() and wp_footer()? These are the template function  calls which handles this kind of action/hook.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to do like this instead:

```
function load_jquery() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js', false, '1.8.1');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}

add_action('init', 'load_jquery');
```

Comment: -1! Actually I answered it in a question's comment. You must use wp_head() and wp_footer() in your template.

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress jquery automatically loaded by wp-load.php. make sure you have wp_head() hook in your header.php

one more thing you can't check using alert(), as its native javascript. try using jQuery method, like.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {

     jQuery("#some_div").html("testing....");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are not using the right hook. You missed an `s`.

The hook should have been like

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_jquery' );
```

[`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) is  the function name, and [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) is the hook name.